# How do I properly insert a document with object that contains another object

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, object

In mongodb I'm wondering how you can properly insert json to the db from the command line with an object that contains an object?

```
db.burgers.insert(
    [
        {'burger': {
            'patty': 'beef',
            'cheese': false,
            'toppings': [
                'ketchup', 'onions', 'pickles'
            ]
        }}
    ]
)
```

When I try the code above, `db.burgers.burger.find()` returns `0`, when I am expecting it to return `1`

The following is how they get returned.

```
db.burgers.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f87b58afd426d861d55b5ff"),
    "burger" : {
        "patty" : "beef",
        "cheese" : false,
        "toppings" : [
            "ketchup",
            "onions",
            "pickles"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In mongodb I'm wondering how you can properly insert json to the db
> from the command line with an object that contains an object?

Your inserting the document into the collection is correct. You can use `insertOne`, `insertMany` or `insert` methods to insert documents. The `insertOne` is specific for insert one document at a time. `insert` and `insertMany` can be used to insert one or more documents at a time.

From the command line, `mongo` shell:

```
> var doc =  { 'burger': {
                       'patty': 'beef',
                       'cheese': false,
                       'toppings': [ 'ketchup', 'onions', 'pickles' ] 
             } }

> db.burgers.insertOne(doc)
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedId" : ObjectId("5f87f68dd039d5cb61ae2251")
}
```

Note the `_id` field is created by the MongoDB.

You can use `insertMany` to insert many documents - an array of JSON documents. For example,

```
var docs_array = [ {... }, {... }, ... ]
db.burgers.insertMany(docs_array)
```

> When I try the code above, db.burgers.burger.find() returns 0, when I
> am expecting it to return 1

You can query the document using the `find` or `findOne` methods. The `find` returns a *cursor* (with multiple documents) and the `findOne` always returns one document (or a `null` if no document is found). For example:

```
> db.burgers.findOne()
> db.burgers.findOne( { _id: ObjectId("5f87f68dd039d5cb61ae2251") } )
```

The above queries return the newly inserted document, above.

Your query `db.burgers.burger.find()` is not correct, I think. If you want only the `burger` field ( this a nested document) to be printed, then use *projection*, like this:

```
> db.burgers.findOne( {}, { burger: 1, _id: 0 } )
{
        "burger" : {
                "patty" : "beef",
                "cheese" : false,
                "toppings" : [
                        "ketchup",
                        "onions",
                        "pickles"
                ]
        }
}
```

Note the *projection* allows output only the specific fields, and exclude others. In the above query, the `_id` field is excluded.

If you want to count documents in the collection use this:

```
> db.burgers.countDocuments({})
```

**Reference:**

- [Insert
  Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/insert-documents/)
- [Query
  Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/query-documents/)
- [Query on Nested
  Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/)